# Simplifying the data in a raster - R

Tags: r, raster, dismo

I have a raster file, which I created from data downloaded from DIVA-GIS: http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown

`nz_map<-raster("NZL1_msk_cov.grd")`

Using `plot()` on this object works great, so there are no issues importing it. The raster object contains a lot of data I don't need, data on land cover. I want a more simple raster object with lon & lat coordinates and a value of 1 for land and NA for ocean.

This raster will be used with the dismo function `randomPoints()` to sample background data for modelling species distribution, so the most important thing is to identify which areas are land(suitable for sampling) and which are ocean(unsuitable).

I can visualise the raster more simply with `plot(!is.na(nz_map5))`. This works well and services for the `randomPoints()` function, but I'm not sure how to edit the color of the map. Doing this:  `plot(!is.na(nz_map5), col="grey")` results in a totally grey block, instead of just colouring the appropriate areas grey; this is why I thought I might be better off with a more simple raster object, to do away with the `!is.na` argument Any ideas?

If anyone knows of a place you could download such files, saving me the hassle- that works, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are similar data for elevation

```
library(raster)
a <- getData("alt", country="NZL")
r <- a[[1]]
plot(r)
```

I think your confusion stems from what happens here

```
x <- !is.na(r)
```

That turns the values to `TRUE` (those that were not `NA`) or `FALSE` (those that were `NA`). So now you have two categories

```
plot(x, col=c("red", "blue"))
```

And now it is no longer a good dataset for `dismo::randomPoints`

If you would rather have `NA` and 1 other value you can do

```
y <- r * 0
plot(y, col="blue")
```

Or

```
 y <- reclassify(y, cbind(-Inf, Inf, 1))
```

But, as you say yourself, for `randomPoints` you can just use the original data.